# Is there a more modern implementation of CORBA?

Tags: corba

I'm figuring that CORBA is considered a legacy technology that just refuses to die.  That being said, I'm curious if there are any known standards out there that are preferred (and are also as platform independent.)

Thoughts?  TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many organization are moving to WebServices and the open standards relating to them (HTTP, WS-*) as alternatives to Corba.

[This article](http://blog.zemi.eu/207/corba-vs-web-services) provides a comparison of the two technologies and offers some recommendations on when to use which.

If you really care about platform independence and protocol standardization - then the [WS-* standards](http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/) are something to look into.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a state of the art modern CORBA implementation using C++11, TAOX11. This uses the new IDL to C++11 language mapping. For TAOX11 see the [TAOX11 website](http://www.taox11.org). TAOX11 is supported on a wide range of platforms and compilers.

Comment: Hi. What is a current backend for your implementation? Looking for a SHM-based thing, because networking delays are just inappropriate in our case.

Comment: We are using TAO as underlying ORB

Comment: TAO has support for shares memory as transport. You can add your own pluggable protocol if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently tried [Google Protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), they seem rather similar to CORBA by design (some kind of IDL with compiler, binary compact messages, etc). It is probably one of the many possible successors.

Web services are good for the right tasks but creating and parsing messages needs more time and text based messages are more bulky than binary ones. REST API with JSON looks like a good solution where binary protocols do not fit well.

Answer (score 0):

[ICE](http://www.zeroc.com/ice.html) from ZeroC aims to be a "better CORBA".

Unfortunately their licensing terms are crap (at least last time I checked with them), as they do not sell developer licenses but only (roughly) per-installation terms.

It *is* offered via GPL license too, if you can live with this.